# VS Code 1.87.0 highlighting word after alt+tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

The problem appeared completely out of the blue. After changing the window (alt+tab), the word on which the cursor was becomes highlighted. Moreover, such a selection cannot be removed by clicking to the side, like manual selection with a cursor. This highlighting only disappears when I start typing something.

I have searched and tried many settings, turned off all extensions, asked chatGPT, nothing helps. This highlighting is very annoying, I want to get rid of it.

Before alt+tab:

[image]

After alt+tab:

[image]

I have searched and tried many settings, turned off all extensions, asked chatGPT, nothing helps. This highlighting is very annoying, I want to get rid of it.

Comment: VSC always highlights occurrences of the same element in the code. So your problem is that it stays if you move the cursor away?

Comment: Yes, it stays even if I clicked in another place. Highlighting removes only when typing. This was not always the case, I would have noticed. It started suddenly one day

Comment: This sounds more like a bug than something you can deactivate in the settings.

Comment: I already reinstalled VS Code :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what's your occurrences highlighting enabled setting set to?

Comment: @СергейКох что не понятного то?) При альт табе выделяется слово на курсоре, выделение которого нельзя снять мышкой (кликом в сторону). Такого поведения не хочу, и не было такого поведения. Бесит, хочу избавиться.

Comment: @starball "editor.occurrencesHighlight": "off",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with VS Code 1.87.0. It should be fixed in 1.87.1.

See the following issue tickets for more info:

- [Occurrence highlighting stuck #206486](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206486)
- [Strange highlight appear when switch to vscode window #206715](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206715)

If you can't wait, apparently you want work around it by setting `"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "true",` (if you don't mind).

Answer (score 0):

When I use **alt+tab**, only the windows replacement window appears.

You could open your keyboard shortcuts(**Ctrl+K Ctrl+S**) and search for the command which using shortcuts **alt+tab**.

[image]

My guesses is that your `selectAllSearchEditorMatches` or `editor.action.selectHighlights` command was replaced with **alt+tab**. Or the problem is caused by other highlighting extensions you have installed.

[image]

Comment: These shortcuts are set to default. I turned extensions off and it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Until the bug is fixed, do this in your settings:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "true",
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a bug, I just switched to prev VSC version. I'm not satisfied with "editor.occurrencesHighlight": "true" setting, but it actually solves the problem.