# How to disable remembering cursor state in Visual Studio Code when exiting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I leave the cursor on some word in the VS code when I exit and open the VS code again. Because of the cursor, a word or several words(if there are duplicates) are highlighted, and will be highlighted until I make some change in the file. How can I turn this off?

Example:

```py
fro(stay cursor here)m datetime import datetime
from random import randrange
```

and after rebooting the VS code all `from` are highlighted

screen sharing video: https://vimeo.com/920805583?share=copy

I disabled everything that could be disabled related to highlighting in settings.json, but the problem remains. I also disabled all extensions and looked at work without them, still the same.

```json
"editor.unicodeHighlight.includeStrings": false,
"editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters": false,
"editor.matchBrackets": "never",
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "off",
"editor.selectionHighlight": false,
"less.hover.documentation": false,
"css.hover.documentation": false,
"scss.hover.documentation": false,
"html.hover.documentation": false,
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints.cycle": false,
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
"editor.lightbulb.enabled": "off",
"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "currentDocument",
"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",
```

Comment: please check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/78120261/11107541 answers this question.